# Form not editable inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to break up the monotony of a long form, making in multi-part by spreading the fields across several bootstrap 4 carousel divs. This has caused odd behaviour where the form text input fields are not editable ***after*** toggling the carousel slide (edit is ok before toggle).

[Fiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/hausv11r/)

**What causes this and how can I fix it?**

(I'm also using a little jquery to show appropriate navigation buttons, but I don't think that should interfere with the actual input editability, eg:)

```
$('#carousel-control-previous').hide(); // start with prev button hidden
$('#btn-submit').hide(); // start with submit button hidden
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by the carousel hijacking the keyboard when focussed (so that the keyboard can control the carousel slide). Fix this by adding `data-keyboard="false"` to the `.carousel` wrapper div.